# Android: How to display a screen for the first time only in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

My app has an initial screen(activity) which asks the user to input their name and then click on the login button. After the user does this, I don't want the app to display this screen ever again, and instead the app should start another activity. I have done some research and found that you are supposed to use shared preferences but I am still confused. The following is the code of the initial screen activity:

```
class StudentNameInput : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_name_input)

       btnStudentLogIn.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    private fun validate(): Boolean {
        if (txt_student_name.text.toString().isEmpty()){
            txt_student_name.error = "Name cannot be empty"
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?){
        when(v?.id){
            R.id.btnStudentLogIn->{
                if(validate()){
                    Log.i(null, "setOnClickListener")
                    val intent = Intent(this, StudentInitialActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save the user name in shared preferences and then when you start the activity you need to check does shared preferences have saved user name, and if yes you start the next activity and finish the current, but if no you stay in the current activity, something like this:

```
class StudentNameInput : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var sharedPref: SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       sharedPref: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        if (wasUserNameSaved()) {
            val intent = Intent(this, StudentInitialActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
            return
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_name_input)

       btnStudentLogIn.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    private fun validate(): Boolean {
        if (txt_student_name.text.toString().isEmpty()){
            txt_student_name.error = "Name cannot be empty"
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?){
        when(v?.id){
            R.id.btnStudentLogIn->{
                if(validate()){
                    Log.i(null, "setOnClickListener")
 sharedPref.edit().putString("user_name", txt_student_name.text.toString()).apply()
                    val intent = Intent(this, StudentInitialActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun wasUserNameSaved(): Boolean {
   return sharedPref.getString("user_name", "").isNotEmpty()
    }
```

Sorry for wrong formatting i wrote it from my phone.